# iOS deep linking: how to embed URL in another URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking

I need to deep link to my app with another URL, say if my custom scheme is:

```
myapp://
```

then the deep linking URL looks like:

```
myapp://?type=url&url=[another URL]
```

The problem is that the "another URL" may contain the separators like ?, /, & etc,  I thought about using quotation mark:

```
myapp://?type=url&url="http://another.url"
```

However the another URL may also have quotation mark in it, so is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly escape all of the special characters in the 2nd URL. I use a utility method I wrote to help:

```
+ (NSString *)encodeString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *result = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("% '\"?=&+<>;:-#\\/~`!"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    return result;
}
```

With that in place (in some helper class or added to some category), you can do the following:

```
NSString *link = @"http://another.url";
NSString *escapedLink = [SomeUtility encodeString:link];

NSString *myURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myapp://?type=url&url=%@", escapedLink];
```

Note that this `encodeString:` method should be used to properly escape any URL parameter value you may ever use to build the query string of a URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is someone else provide the link, so I cannot do these encoding for it.

Comment: What do you mean? Is someone passing you the deep link (the one that needs to be escaped) or is someone passing you the final URL? If the former then you can escape it using my answer. If the latter, then the other person must properly escape the deep link before sending you the final URL.